# Запретить запуск копии исполняемого файла

Tags: unix

Хотелось бы увидеть способ позволяющий запретить запуск второй копии исполняемого файла. При условии, что:

- файл может быть переименован;
- процесс может получить SIGKILL;
- желательно обойтись чистыми средствами unix;
- желательно, чтобы способ был легко реалезуем как для бинариков, так и для bash-скриптов.

Answer (score 1):

Универсальный вариант:

```
lockfile filename && (execute; rm -f filename)
```

Вариант для демонов:

```
start-stop-daemon ...
```

Вариант для процесса с уникальным неизменяемым именем:

```
#!/bin/bash
# Подсчитать количество запущеных процессов с именем task (за искючением grep)
# Выйти из скрипта, если это количество больше нуля, так как процесс уже запущен
count=`ps -ef |grep "task" |grep -v grep |wc -l`
if [ $pc -gt 0 ] ; then
    exit 0
fi
./task
```